# Laravel eloquent query table names case insensitive

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to make eloquent queries case insensitive? An issue came when I decided to move my website to production (move from my local machine to the host server). MariaDB on my host server is case sensitive and I don't have an access to its config file. The problem is that I have a `Users` table which is used in laravel auth. The queries of laravel in lower case like:

```
select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1
```

I really need to know how to make queries case insensitive, because I have hundreds queries with `Users` table.

Comment: change `$table` in your model file.

Comment: in eloquent use the define `protected $table = 'Users';` within the Users model

Comment: @Nolesh, you may want to write custom authentication code? Also, you may want to ask for .conf file for Mariadb. You can disable case sensitivity

Comment: @Nolesh to be fair, you can't ask a question about Eloquent, yet you're using raw queries.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, You were right! I was pretty sure that I had `protected $table = 'Users';` in my model. But it did not! It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As we've been discussing in the comments, adding the `protected $table = 'StRaNgE-tAbLe-NaMe';` to a MyModel.php will work on a case-by-case basis.

If you have a more structured naming convention, but it does not follow laravel's default, then you could create a trait or model base class to override Model getTable().

$model->getTable() looks like this...

```
/**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if (! isset($this->table)) {
        return str_replace(
            '\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this)))
        );
    }

    return $this->table;
}
```

Comment: If he uses raw queries, this won't work. (He probably commented after your answer)

Comment: My raw queries have correct syntax. So, this method should work, but I am not going to check it, because defining `protected $table = 'Users';` in my model solved my issue.

Comment: Yes, `protected $table` is my goto solution when I have non-laravel-standard tables in a db.  I've never actually needed to use the above solution, but it may be of use if you ever have systemically different table naming pattern.